# Using static factory methods to prevent unwanted input

Tags: java, object-oriented, static-methods

Many years ago, I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345658/validating-construcor-parameters-determined-by-another-parameter/44345789) a problem I had with some code and received a well written detailed answer that suggested the use of factory methods. I liked this approach, because I can provide a method name to let clients know 
what was being created, and to prevent wrong parameters.

```
// Left out additonal parameters and validation
private Student(StudentType type, List<String> documents) {
    this.type = type;
    this.documents = documents;
}

public static Student createDomestic() {
    return new Student(StudentType.DOMESTIC), Collections.emptyList());
}

public static Student createInternational(List<Document> documents) {
    return new Student(StudentType.INTERNATIONAL, new ArrayList<>(documents);
}
```

**Benefits**:

- I don't need a private method to validate the `List` based on the
  `StudentType`, it made the code shorter and cleaner. All I needed was
  to check if the `List` provided for the `International` students
  contained documents (by checking the length of the `List`).
- The static factory prevents clients from assigning a `Domestic`
  student a `List` of documents, which according to the requirements it
  shouldn't have.

Leaving aside the [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), is using a `static` factory method the way it was suggested on SO, considered a code smell or bad practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a perfectly good use of static factory methods.

The requirement that a international student should have documents, but a domestic student shouldn't, does make me question why you didn't use an object hierarchy in which you have `DomesticStudent` and `InternationalStudent` classes deriving from `Student`, but I'll assume that there were other requirements driving that decision.

Answer (score 0):

An simpler alternative might be to have a single constructor taking a single parameter, the List.  Skeletal code:

```
public Student(List docs) {
  this.documents = docs;
  this.type = (docs.length() > 0)?
                         StudentType.INTERNATIONAL :
                         StudentType.DOMESTIC;
}
```

Not sure if this makes more sense for your application.

Also, makes you wonder if the `type` field is required - couldn't you just check for docs.length?  e.g.

```
public boolean isInternational() {
  return docs.length() > 0;
}
```

Comment: I would advise against this approach. Say there was a bug in the calling code which meant that it attempted to create an international student but failed to supply documents. This code would just happily create a domestic student instead. Likewise, erroneously adding documents to a domestic student would result in the creation of an international student.

Comment: @Pete valid point, if you wish to require that the caller know whether the student is domestic / international.  Or do they simply know if they have documents?  My proposal encapsulates the domestic / international logic.

Comment: @user949300 - you could keep your `isInternational()` method but rewrite the code to check the `enum` rather than the `List`

Comment: @user949300 - This might go beyond the scope of the question, but I don't think that the `Student` should determine if it's `Domestic` or `International`. The `University` object would decide. In reality, while the student will know if he or she is domestic or international, the university will gather the documents and confirm. Simply telling the university official you're domestic or international won't mean much, why should they take your word over gathering the documents and checking?